# Чтение бинарного файла С#

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо считать матрицу с бинарного файла (расширение .dat ) где первые два элемента идут целые числа указывающие количество строк и столбцов а затем элементы построчно. Прошу помощи

Comment: Построчно? В бинарном файле?

Comment: В смысле в бинарном файле они идут в виде кода и если считывать то элементы необходимо записывать построчно в матрицу

Comment: Без содержимого этого файла невозможно воспроизвести класс с нужными свойствами. Откройте этот файл в студии, скопируйте его содержимое и вставьте сюда в свой вопрос.

Comment: _целые числа_ - какие именно: `short`, `int`, `long`? А элементы какого типа? Нужно точно знать, сколько байт они занимают.

Comment: В том и вопрос что нужен код чтобы выводил этот файл , значения типа int.Студия не открывает .dat файлы

Comment: Все отрывает студия. Достаточно в меню выбрать "Открыть файл" выбрать формат "Все файлы", найти ваш dat и открыть его.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону этого класса BinaryReader это должно вам помочь

Comment: Если файл `.dat` это не факт, что файл бинарный, и если `.txt` это ещё не значит что текстовый, хотя по правилу хорошего тона, этого стоит придерживаться. Ответы вам даны вполне хорошие, не понятно почему они вам не подходят. Наверное вам стоит почитать методичку. Дайте HEX-дамп вашего файла, потому что по файлу как раз вопросы

Answer (score -1):

С выше описанного ТЗ сделал предположения:

```
    public static Int32[,] ReaderArray(String path)
    {
        Int32[,] a = null;
        // создаем объект BinaryReader
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            // пока не достигнут конец файла
            // считываем каждое значение из файла
            while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
            {
                var n = reader.ReadInt32();
                var m = reader.ReadInt32();
                a = new Int32[n, m];
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (Int32 j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        a[i, j] = reader.ReadInt32();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: У вас конструктор такой `public Array(Int32 n, Int32 m, Int32[,] array)` , а создаете инстанс так почему-то `Array array = new Array();`. Да, и называть собственные типы также как .Net встроенные типы - это моветон.

Comment: @Bulson, я думаю это не принципиально, а имена что пришло первое в голову.

Comment: @Bulson у любой структуры всегда есть конструктор по умолчанию

Comment: @Yaroslav цикл у вас лишний, вы же больше одной матрицы все равно вернуть не можете. Структура Array тоже лишняя, ее поля `n` и `m` дублируют информацию которая уже содержится в массиве.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, какой из циклов? Я думал что Array, будет приемлеммо

Comment: @Yaroslav внешний цикл. Зачем вы считываете из файла неограниченное количество последовательных матриц, если в задаче сказано считать одну?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, так я и читаю одну матрицу

Comment: @Yaroslav посмотрите свой код еще раз!

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, думаю вы за это говорили

Answer (score -1):

Я предполагаю что тебя интересует сериализация.

То есть ты сначала сохраняешь данные, а потом считываешь их.

То есть ты создаешь свой личный класс

```
[Serializable]
public MyBinaryClass
{
//заполняешь всем, что тебе нужно
}
```

А потом используешь

```
public static class Serializator
{
    public static void Serialize(string pathOrFileName, object objToSerialise)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialise);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string pathOrFileName) 
    {
        T items;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            items = (T) bin.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

следующим образом:

```
MyBinaryClass someMatrix = new MyBinaryClass();

Serializator.Serialize("data.dat", someMatrix);//пример сохранения

someMatrix = Serializator.Deserialize<MyBinaryClass >("data.dat");//пример подгрузки
```

**PS: если файл УЖЕ существует, то это скорее всего не сработает.**

Comment: Не, мне кажется автор совсем неблагодарный