# Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно создать класс для десериализации JSON?

Tags: c#, json

```
{
"success": true,
"items": {
    "\u2605 Bayonet": {
        "name": "\u2605 Bayonet",
        "safe_price": "118.31",
        "safe_net_price": "110.60",
        "ongoing_price_manipulation": false,
        "total_volume": 3148,
        "7_days": {
            "median_price": "118.31",
            "median_net_price": "110.60",
            "average_price": "118.25",
            "average_net_price": "102.84",
            "lowest_price": "100.00",
            "lowest_net_price": "86.97",
            "highest_price": "132.25",
            "highest_net_price": "115.00",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "5.46",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.046173361522199,
            "trend": -0.050389739620763,
            "volume": 94
        },
        "30_days": {
            "median_price": "138.94",
            "median_net_price": "129.88",
            "average_price": "135.69",
            "average_net_price": "118.00",
            "lowest_price": "56.03",
            "lowest_net_price": "48.73",
            "highest_price": "156.60",
            "highest_net_price": "136.19",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "10.81",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.079666887758862,
            "trend": -0.23473444256315,
            "volume": 422
        },
        "all_time": {
            "median_price": "148.00",
            "median_net_price": "138.35",
            "average_price": "147.33",
            "average_net_price": "128.12",
            "lowest_price": "0.17",
            "lowest_net_price": "0.15",
            "highest_price": "179.24",
            "highest_net_price": "155.87",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "9.02",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.061223104595127,
            "trend": -0.032006931201406,
            "volume": 3148
        },
        "first_seen": 1444261666
    },
    // etc ...
    "\u2605 Bayonet | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred)": {
        "name": "\u2605 Bayonet | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred)",
        "safe_price": "81.21",
        "safe_net_price": "70.62",
        "ongoing_price_manipulation": false,
        "total_volume": 1,
        "7_days": {
            "volume": 0
        },
        "30_days": {
            "median_price": "81.21",
            "median_net_price": "70.62",
            "average_price": "81.21",
            "average_net_price": "70.62",
            "lowest_price": "81.21",
            "lowest_net_price": "70.62",
            "highest_price": "81.21",
            "highest_net_price": "70.62",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "0.00",
            "deviation_percentage": 0,
            "trend": 0,
            "volume": 1
        },
        "all_time": {
            "median_price": "81.21",
            "median_net_price": "70.62",
            "average_price": "81.21",
            "average_net_price": "70.62",
            "lowest_price": "81.21",
            "lowest_net_price": "70.62",
            "highest_price": "81.21",
            "highest_net_price": "70.62",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "0.00",
            "deviation_percentage": 0,
            "trend": 0,
            "volume": 1
        },
        "first_seen": 1466590845
    },
    // etc ...
    "XM1014 | VariCamo Blue (Well-Worn)": {
        "name": "XM1014 | VariCamo Blue (Well-Worn)",
        "safe_price": "0.89",
        "safe_net_price": "0.84",
        "ongoing_price_manipulation": false,
        "total_volume": 763,
        "7_days": {
            "median_price": "0.89",
            "median_net_price": "0.84",
            "average_price": "0.90",
            "average_net_price": "0.80",
            "lowest_price": "0.65",
            "lowest_net_price": "0.58",
            "highest_price": "1.08",
            "highest_net_price": "0.95",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "0.09",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.1,
            "trend": -0.10752688172043,
            "volume": 30
        },
        "30_days": {
            "median_price": "1.12",
            "median_net_price": "0.99",
            "average_price": "1.10",
            "average_net_price": "0.96",
            "lowest_price": "0.65",
            "lowest_net_price": "0.58",
            "highest_price": "1.51",
            "highest_net_price": "1.32",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "0.16",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.14545454545455,
            "trend": -0.32851070467574,
            "volume": 153
        },
        "all_time": {
            "median_price": "1.70",
            "median_net_price": "1.49",
            "average_price": "1.71",
            "average_net_price": "1.50",
            "lowest_price": "0.03",
            "lowest_net_price": "0.01",
            "highest_price": "11.50",
            "highest_net_price": "10.00",
            "mean_absolute_deviation": "0.41",
            "deviation_percentage": 0.23976608187135,
            "trend": -0.67071929583276,
            "volume": 763
        },
        "first_seen": 1444277043
    }
},
"build_time": 19954,
"updated_at": 1467408505
```

}

Запутался в том моменте, что в "items" каждый новый предмет идет с новым именем.
На данный момент вот что имею:

```
   public class 7Days
{
    public string median_price { get; set; }
    public string median_net_price { get; set; }
    public string average_price { get; set; }
    public string average_net_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
    public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
    public double trend { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class 30Days
{
    public string median_price { get; set; }
    public string median_net_price { get; set; }
    public string average_price { get; set; }
    public string average_net_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
    public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
    public double trend { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class AllTime
{
    public string median_price { get; set; }
    public string median_net_price { get; set; }
    public string average_price { get; set; }
    public string average_net_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_price { get; set; }
    public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_price { get; set; }
    public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
    public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
    public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
    public double trend { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Bayonet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string safe_price { get; set; }
    public string safe_net_price { get; set; }
    public bool ongoing_price_manipulation { get; set; }
    public int total_volume { get; set; }
    public 7Days 7_days { get; set; }
    public 30Days 30_days { get; set; }
    public AllTime all_time { get; set; }
    public int first_seen { get; set; }
}

public class BayonetBrightWaterBattleScarred
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string safe_price { get; set; }
    public string safe_net_price { get; set; }
    public bool ongoing_price_manipulation { get; set; }
    public int total_volume { get; set; }
    public  7_days { get; set; }
    public  30_days { get; set; }
    public  all_time { get; set; }
    public int first_seen { get; set; }
}

public class XM1014VariCamoBlueWellWorn
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string safe_price { get; set; }
    public string safe_net_price { get; set; }
    public bool ongoing_price_manipulation { get; set; }
    public int total_volume { get; set; }
    public  7_days { get; set; }
    public  30_days { get; set; }
    public  all_time { get; set; }
    public int first_seen { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public Bayonet ★ Bayonet { get; set; }
    public BayonetBrightWaterBattleScarred ★ Bayonet | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred) { get; set; }
    public XM1014VariCamoBlueWellWorn XM1014 | VariCamo Blue (Well-Worn) { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
    public int build_time { get; set; }
    public int updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

Но мне нужно, десериализовать json где очень много предметов с разными именами, подскажите, как мне избежать создание классов с каждым именем предмета? с Наступающим всех )))

UPD. Переделал классы, вот, что получилось:

```
{
public class _7Days
{
public string median_price { get; set; }
public string median_net_price { get; set; }
public string average_price { get; set; }
public string average_net_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
public string highest_price { get; set; }
public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
public double trend { get; set; }
public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class _30Days
{
public string median_price { get; set; }
public string median_net_price { get; set; }
public string average_price { get; set; }
public string average_net_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
public string highest_price { get; set; }
public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
public double trend { get; set; }
public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class _AllTime
{
public string median_price { get; set; }
public string median_net_price { get; set; }
public string average_price { get; set; }
public string average_net_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_price { get; set; }
public string lowest_net_price { get; set; }
public string highest_price { get; set; }
public string highest_net_price { get; set; }
public string mean_absolute_deviation { get; set; }
public double deviation_percentage { get; set; }
public double trend { get; set; }
public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string safe_price { get; set; }
public string safe_net_price { get; set; }
public bool ongoing_price_manipulation { get; set; }
public int total_volume { get; set; }
public _AllTime all_time { get; set; }
public _7Days _7_days { get; set; }
public _30Days _30_days { get; set; }


public int first_seen { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
public bool success { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Item> item { get; set; }
public int build_time { get; set; }
public int updated_at { get; set; }
}
}
```

Создал дополнительный класс, который считывает json :

```
public static Rootobject GetRoot()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\DB.json";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        string itemDB = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(itemDB);                

    }
```

В своей программе вызываю:

```
Rootobject itemsDB = PricerApi.GetRoot();
```

но в itemsDB поле item=null, хотя когда выполняется чтение из файла и десериализация, то в поле item все предметы присутствуют и я их открываю и просматриваю, всё в точности как и должно быть в json, что я сделал не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/914890/261244

Comment: @AK @AK я прочитал эту тему, у меня работает код, если тело json я привожу к виду: `{"XM1014 | VariCamo Blue (Well-Worn)": {
        pro-ty
        "7_days": {
pro-ty
        },
        "30_days": {
pro-ty   
        },
        "all_time": {
  pro-ty     
        },
pro-ty
    }
}` Но не получается когда Dictionary на верхнем уровне оказывается вложенным, т.е. вместе с Dictionary если еще несколько property на одном уровне `public class Rootobject
{
public bool success 
public Dictionary<string, Item> item { get; set; }
public int build_time
public int updated_at 
}`

Comment: В том ответе, что я привёл как дубликат, есть ссылка на ресурс, который генерирует классы - вы им воспользовались или сами пытаетесь нащупать правильный ответ?

Comment: @AK Я пытался генерировать там классы, но ответ приходил без словаря, поэтому мне не подошел этот способ, но теперь я уже разобрался, в чем была моя ошибка! Спасибо за помощь и за полезную информацию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина проблемы - несовпадение имен полей и их PropertyName в json

Для поля items будет оптимальным изменение имени поля:

```
public Dictionary<string, Item> items { get; set; }
```

Однако, у вас имеется еще одно несовпадение - по полям _7_days и _30_days. Здесь замена недопустима, т.к. PropertyName начинается с цифры. 
Здесь поможет объявление PropertyName перед полем:

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "7_days")]
        public _7Days _7_days { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "30_days")]
        public _30Days _30_days { get; set; }
```

Comment: Да, по итогу я пришел к такому же выводу, items я исправил, но забыл про `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "7_days")]` теперь всё работает верно, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @KonstantinNikishonkov если вы хотите поблагодарить автора ответа, то поставьте слева от ответа галку.